# почему ничего не покаывается

Tags: php, sql

нашёл пример работы создания дерева но не могу выполнить помогите

```html
     require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bd.php');
     $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM drive");
    
    
     $table = $stmt->fetchAll(); 


$array = array();  //выходной массив

function recursive($data, $idParent = 0, $level = 0){
    global $array;

    foreach ($data as $row)   { //перебираем строки
        if ($row['idParent'] == $idParent)   { //Начинаем со строк, idParent которых передан в функцию, у нас это 0, т.е. корень сайта
            //Собираем строку в ассоциативный массив
            $_row['id']    = $row['id'];
            $_row['idParent']    = $row['idParent'];
            $_row['path']   = $_row['path']   = str_pad('', $level*3, '.').$row['path']; //Функцией str_pad добавляем точки
            $_row['level']  = $level;       //Добавляем уровень

            $array[] = $_row; //Прибавляем каждую строку к выходному массиву

            //Строка обработана, теперь запустим эту же функцию для текущего id, то есть
            //пойдёт обратотка дочерней строки (у которой этот id является idParent-ом)
            recursive($data, $row['id'], $level + 1);

            
        }

    }

}

recursive($table); //Запускаем
```

вот пример https://habrahabr.ru/post/280944/
ошибок нет но я не пойму где вывести массив чтобы результат был

Comment: На странице `print_r`'ом не вариант?

Comment: пробовал только массив $table

Comment: @Byulent в ссылке как я понял таблица должна быть

Comment: Тогда сделайте функцию, которая выводит данный массив таблицей.

Comment: так вот это я и не могу как в статье

Comment: тогда так вопрос и поставьте - "есть массив такой структуры, как вывести его в такую таблицу"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array(
    'id' => 1,
    'idParent' => 0,
    'path' => '.',
    'level' => '0'
    ),
    array(
    'id' => 2,
    'idParent' => 0,
    'path' => '..',
    'level' => '0'
    ),
    array(
    'id' => 3,
    'idParent' => 1,
    'path' => '/dev',
    'level' => '0'
    ),
);

print '<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>UID</th>
<th>PID</th>
<th>PATH</th>
<th>LEVEL</th>
</tr>
';
foreach ($array as $row) {
    print '<tr>';
    printf(str_repeat("<td>%s</td>", 4), $row['id'], $row['idParent'], $row['path'], $row['level']);
    print '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';

?>
```

С внешним видом разберетесь сами?

Вопрос странный, пожалуйста, не копируйте пример, а разберитесь - что делает каждая буква, каждое слово и каждая строка. **И напишите свой код, который будет лучше примера**

Если у вас трудности с построением HTML-текста таблицы, просто скопированный пример построения рекурсивного древа нужно отложить, и разобраться сначала в азах

Плюс в зависимости от задачи и данных иногда для обхода лучше использовать не рекурсивный вызов, а цикл. Попробуйте лучше понять задачу - что же в итоге нужно сделать?